# AWS ECR user is not authorized to perform: ecr-public:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

I am facing the following issue when attempting to retrieve an authentication token and authenticate your Docker client to your registry:

```
user is not authorized to perform: ecr-public:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
```

I was able to push an image to my private repository just fine without issue. I am using an EC2 ubuntu image to perform these push commands found in AWS dashboard. I made sure the user has role: `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess`

Answer (score 25):

I found the following roles to work. Make sure you attach these policies to your group or user in IAM:

**Private registry:**
AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess

**Public registry:**
AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess

Answer (score 9):

As per [ECR Public docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECRPublic/latest/APIReference/API_GetAuthorizationToken.html), IAM principals need the following **two** actions to call `GetAuthorizationToken`:

- `ecr-public:GetAuthorizationToken`
- `sts:GetServiceBearerToken`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html#security_iam_id-based-policy-examples-console) you need to add
`AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicReadOnly` permission to your user.

Answer (score 0):

I added this and it worked

```
Role: AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess
```